# Working C# Site has VB Master Page - is this preventing JQuery from working?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I've been having a problem over the last day of getting Unobtrusive Verification to work as JQuery is being ignored despite being set up in a ScriptManager in a master page, seemingly correctly.

I've been trying another solution of creating a Global.asax file and putting this code in:

```
<script runat="server">
void Application_Start(object sender,EventArgs e) {
//code runs at app startup
string JQueryVer = "2.1.4";
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition {
Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-"+JQueryVer + ".js",
DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-"+JQueryVer + ".js",
CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + "min.js",
CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
});
}
```

Whilst doing this, I noticed that the Master Page for the site is in VB while the rest is in C# yet besides the issue I mention, the site seems fine. I should ad that the .vb file just seems to be default placeholder code:

```
Partial Class MasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
End Class
```

Could this be causing the problem and if so how do I convert the code behind file to .cs like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

without having to redo all my pages that are already applied to the .vb master page? I did just try kludging the .cs code in (copied from from a new .cs Master Page) but its not allowing the filename and extension to be renamed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Kw

**Edit:**

I recreated the Masterpage but with a .CS code behind file and rebuilt a page that used it. I also inserted the Global.asax file and now it all works. So it seems that the Master page with VB code behind wasn't the problem and that using the Global.asax file forced JQuery to work. However I still don't know why the Script Manager method is failing - anyone know?

I hope this solution helps people with similar issues.

**Edit**

There are typos on that file, so beware. I had to type this from a screengrab so a few errors crept in, although it still seemed to work. Here is a corrected version:

```
   //code runs at app startup
    string JQueryVer = "2.1.4";
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
      Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
      DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
      CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".min.js",
      CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + JQueryVer + ".js",
      CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true,
      LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
    });
  }
```

Comment: Server side language shouldn't have any affect on whether or not a client side language is working. Have you tried looking in your browser's JavaScript console to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: Thanks, and you're right the .vb code wasn't the issue as it all works once I put the Global.asax file in to reference JQuery across the site. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The error report stated that the page needs JQuery but it is not available. Despite hours of looking at similar issues and experimentation I was unable to get the Script manager method to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that jquery.js file path is correct or not?

Comment: There are typos on that file, so beware. I had to type this from a screengrab so a few errors crept in, although it still seemed to work. Here is a corrected version: